# How to pass float from one script to another in Unity 5? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity 5 Personal edition.. I'm trying to pass float from one script to another, but I get this error:

> Assets/CameraTracksPlayer.cs(15,36): error CS1061: Type
>   `ClimberMovement' does not contain a definition for`stopCamera' and
>   no extension method `stopCamera' of type`ClimberMovement' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraTracksPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform player;
    float isDead;
    float offsetY;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        GameObject go = GameObject.Find ("MainCamera");
        ClimberMovement dying = go.GetComponent <ClimberMovement> ();
        float died = dying.stopCamera; //this line gets error!
        isDead = died;


        GameObject player_go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0];

        if (player_go == null) {
            Debug.LogError("Ne dela ker ni taga Player");
            return;
        }
        player = player_go.transform;

        offsetY = transform.position.y - player.position.y;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (player != null && isDead == 1) {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        }
        else if (player != null) {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            pos.y = player.position.y + offsetY;
            transform.position = pos;
        }

    }

}
```

This is the code of the script from which I am trying to pass variable:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClimberMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public Vector3 climbVelocity;
    public Vector3 climbVelocityJump;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public bool stopCamera = false;

    bool didClimb = false;
    bool didJump = false;
    bool jumping = false;
    bool jumping2 = false;

    Animator animator;

    bool dead = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ();
        animator.SetTrigger("DoClimb");
    }

    //do gfx input update here
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            didClimb = true;
            //didJump = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            jumping2 = true;
        }
    }

    // do physics engine update here
    void FixedUpdate () {

        velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if(didClimb == true){
            didClimb = false;
            jumping = true;
            velocity += climbVelocity;
        }

        else if (jumping2 == true && dead == false) {
            jumping = false;
            jumping2 = false;
            velocity += climbVelocityJump;
        }

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);

        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (transform.position.x <= -3.9f) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (-3.9f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            if (transform.position.x == -3.9f) {
                dead = true;
                stopCamera = true;
                animator.SetTrigger ("Death");
                velocity.y = -5f;
                velocity.x = -5f;
            }
        } else if (transform.position.x >= -1f) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (-1f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Strange, this code in it's current form should work. Are you sure you copied it as it is?

Comment: Also, please, don't use tags without reading their description. `unity` tag is not about Unity game engine.

Comment: By the way — you seem to use `isDead` of `float` type to save a boolean value. C# (and almost all other modern languages) has a special type for that, `bool`.

Comment: @MaxYankov Sorry about the tag.. I've change it to bool but still dont work.. is it maybe the problem that scripts are not in the same game object?

Comment: Just test your code in my own unity Scene, it works well. Can you give us your whole Climber Movement script please ?

Comment: @Fisheroid if the Script was not in gameObject you should have a nullReferenceException at getComponent line

Comment: @Laykker I updated the code of ClimberMovement in the question post.

Comment: @Laykker Yes, now I get this: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CameraTracksPlayer.Start () (at Assets/CameraTracksPlayer.cs:14)

Comment: Well, if you updated the type to `bool` in one script and not in the other, of course you'll get an error — but it would be a different type of error, a type error. C# is a strongly, statically typed language, so it will not allow you to implicitly convert most of the types to one another and provide show an error during compilation.

Comment: Wait. So, you don't get error that you described in the question anymore? The code compiles now?

Comment: @Fisheroid If you get NullReferenceException add your script ClimberMovement on your "MainCamera"

Comment: Yes, now I don't get error described int the question.. but I get NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Laykker Okay, now it works. Camera is a bit off but I'll fix that.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - You want to cast `public bool stopCamera = false;` in `float died`.

Try to change `float died` with `bool died`

2 - If you have a NullReferenceException, it means it doesnt find your script in your "MainCamera" gameobject.

Try to add your script "ClimberMovement" in your "MainCamera" gameobject.

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion for your case would be to have a method that returns that value:

```
public float stopCameraValue(){
return stopCamera;
}
```

What i guess is that the monobehaviour is preventing you from accessing directly to that variable, thus having an error. Since you are not instatiating the  ClimberMovement class in the CameraTracksPlayer class, it may think that it is not instatiated at compile time.